# PHP Selecting and Inner joining tables Issue.

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make it where it will get all of the users tournament_regid for the events, but its only select the first entry in my database, and then when I join the two tables based on that regid it is only displaying the one entry. 
Any Ideas on how I'm able to get all of the users tournament_regid's?

This is what I currently have:

```
   <?

    $stmt = $DB_con->prepare('SELECT tournament_regid, paid FROM tournament_registration WHERE userid= :session_id');
        $stmt->bindParam(':session_id', $_SESSION['user']['id']);   
        $stmt->execute();
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $regid = $row['tournament_regid'];
        ?>  

        <?
        $stmt = $DB_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM tournament_registration JOIN tournaments ON tournament_registration.tournament_regid = tournaments.tournamentid WHERE tournaments.tournamentid = :regid");
        $stmt->bindParam(':regid', $regid);
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    {

            ?>

        <h1> Event Name: <? echo $row['tournament_name'];?> </h1>
        <h1> Event Date: <? echo $row['tournament_date'];?> </h1>
        <h1> Event Time: <? echo $row['tournament_time'];?> </h1>
        <h1> Event Desc: <? echo $row['tournament_dec'];?> </h1>
        <h1> Paid: <? echo $row['paid'];?> </h1>
        <h1> <? echo $row[''];?> </h1>
        <a href="viewevent.php?event_id=<?php echo $row['tournament_regid'];?>"> VIEW Event Details  </a>
        <h1>
        <?php echo $regid;?>
        </h1>
        <?
    }
    }
        ?>
```

Updated SQL Query: Issue now is that it looks like its getting everyone's Stuff? Because there is a lot of data displaying now.

```
<? 
$stmt = $DB_con->prepare("

SELECT 
   *
FROM
   users
INNER JOIN
    tournament_registration ON tournament_registration.userid = :userid
INNER JOIN
    tournaments ON tournaments.tournamentid = tournament_registration.tournament_regid
");
$stmt->bindParam(':userid', $_SESSION['user']['id']);
$stmt->execute();
while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{

        ?>
```

Comment: You overwrite `$stmt` in your loop. Use different variable names. You also can probably do this with one query.

Comment: Run a query inside a loop is often a signal of poor code/query design. Try to rewrite your SQL query to make only one database query, then show the data you want using PHP.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte What I could do Is inner join the users table and select their userid and then join the tournament_registration and tournaments?

Comment: Use the `where` to filter down the data, not the `on`.

Comment: @user3783243 When I change it from on to where it stops showing the info. I changed it to this `SELECT 
   *
FROM
   users
INNER JOIN
    tournament_registration WHERE tournament_registration.userid = :userid
INNER JOIN
    tournaments  WHERE tournaments.tournamentid = tournament_registration.tournament_regid`

Comment: You can't have 2 `where`s and you need and `on` and a `where`. Try `SELECT * FROM users 
INNER JOIN tournament_registration 
on tournament_registration.userid = users.userid 
INNER JOIN tournaments
on tournaments.tournamentid = tournament_registration.tournament_regid
WHERE users.userid = :userid`.

Comment: Didn't show any data from the database.

Comment: When I do a WHERE and an ON statement.

Comment: This sounds much more like a mysql JOIN question than a PHP question. Please add schemes so we can execute as you are... or I answered the PHP part of it already. You could just alter the variable names the better approach though is going to be further along.

Answer (score 0):

"SELECT 
   tournament_registration.tournament_regid
FROM
   users
INNER JOIN
    tournament_registration ON tournament_registration.userid = users.userid
INNER JOIN
    tournaments ON tournaments.tournamentid = tournament_registration.tournament_regid
"

use this updated sql query to achieve it